# Using ` Eigen::aligned_allocator` on `std::vector` on classes containing Eigen types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, eigen, memory-alignment

According to [Eigen's documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStlContainers.html) when creating a `std::vector` with a *"fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types"*, the `Eigen::aligned_allocator` **must** be used, e.g.:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector4f,Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Vector4f> > myVector;
```

I have a class containing *fixed-size* Eigen members, and a `std::vector` of that class, e.g.:

```
class myClass{
public:    Eigen::Vector2d v;
}
//...
std::vector<myClass> myVector;
std::vector<myClass*> myPtrVector;
```

Question: **Am I required to use `Eigen::aligned_allocator` for vectors of classes containing Eigen members (the same way as vectors of Eigen types directly)?**

(I'm using Visual Studio 2013, if that matters)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is yes.

The very first sentence on the [page you referenced](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStlContainers.html) says "... or classes having members of such types, requires taking the following two steps

- A 16-byte-aligned allocator must be used. Eigen does provide one ready for use: aligned_allocator.
- If you want to use the std::vector container, you need to #include .
  "